# Rubyの演算子の優先順位について

Tags: ruby

Rubyの演算子は優先順位が高い順に*、+、>、=なので

```
m=m*3+1>n
```

の場合は

```
m=(m*3+1>n)
```

と同義になるのは納得がいきます。

しかし、(比較演算子からみて)これと左右を逆にした

```
n<m=m*3+1
```

が

```
(n<m)=m*3+1
```

と同義にならず、

```
n<(m=m*3+1)
```

と同義になるのは演算子の優先順位からして違和感を覚えます。
優先順位の他に何か規則があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n<m`はいわゆる左辺値ではないからだと思います。Rubyの公式リファレンスでも、[「代入式の左辺は以下のいずれかでなければなりません」](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2foperator.html#assign)として、代入式の左辺になりうるものを列挙しています。

Comment: モヤモヤがスッキリしました。有難うございました。